# Stumped: Detect identical sequence of integers in two integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays, compare

First and foremost, I'm a java newb. I've been searching for a concise approach to this problem that doesn't involve lists or hash tables, but haven't found it yet:

**Note this is not a homework assignment, BUT it is Exercise #14 in Chapter 7 of "Building Java Programs"

Write a method called contains that accepts two arrays of integers as parameters and returns a boolean indication whether or not the elements of the second array appear in the first.

Example:

```
Integer[] list1 = {1,6,2,1,4,1,2,1,8};

Integer[] list2 = {1,2,1};
```

Calling `contains(list1, list2)` would return `true`. I get the idea of nested for loops that can iterate through an array, but I can't see a clear solution:

```
public static Boolean contains(Integer[] listOfNumbers1, Integer[] listOfNumbers2){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < listOfNumbers2.length; i++){

        for(int j = 0 ; j < listOfNumbers1.length; j++){

        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You first need to decide if you want to search for sequence (as said in title) or compare as sets - just presence of all elements of second set in first set (as seem to be in the task). Code will be significantly different.

Answer (score 2):

(You don't really specify if the duplicates need to be considered, from you example it looks like you are attempting to see if array1 has all the elements of array2 in order)

There are several different cases to consider:

```
1. array2 is longer than array1:
       if this is the case the result must be false because array1 can't 
       possibly have the same elements in order since array2 is longer

2. array2 is the same size as array1: 
       for this step you can use a single loop and compare the elements in order, 
       if you find a  mismatch then array1 does not contain array2

       for i from 0 to length do
           if array1[i] != array2[i]
              // false
           end
       end
       // true

3. array2 is shorter than array1:
       for this case you need to examine every array2.length elements from array1 
       and see if they match array2

       matches = 0
       for i from 0 to array1.length do
           for j from 0 to array2.length do
               if array1[i] == array2[j] 
                  // increment i
                  // increment matches
               end
           end
           if matches == array2.length
               // true
           else
               // false
           end
           matches = 0  // reset matches
       end
```

Comment: +1. Good writeup on sequence match. Note that there are more optimal solutions for that problem when you move beyond basic - search for "substring search algorithms".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah I had considered whether or not to link to more complex matching algorithms, Warshall's or Floyd's for instance, but I decided not to because this seems like a more introductory question.  It is a good idea to point it out though, thanks I will make an edit.

Comment: #1 and #2 are a special case of #3, where the outer loop will have 0 or 1 iteration respectively. I'd say there is no performance to be gained, and much clarity to be lost by separating the cases so.

Comment: @Amadan I was just trying to sketch out some pseudocode to help the OP in the right direction, but as you say they can just be combined into the single nested for.

Answer (score 1):

So basically we want to iterate through each position in the search array (`listOfNumbers1`) and check whether it is the start of the sequence we are looking for (`listOfNumbers2`)

```
// Loops through the search array
for( int i = 0; i < listOfNumbers1.length; i++ )
{
    boolean found = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < listOfNumbers2.length; j++ )
    {
        /* Check if the following conditions hold
           - Not going to cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
           - Values do **not** match => set found to false */
        if( i+j < listOfNumbers1.length && listOfNumbers1[i + j] != listOfNumbers2[j] )
        {
            // Didn't find the sequence here
            found = false;
        }
    }

    // If found is still true, we have found the sequence and can exit
    if( found ) return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: More efficiently; change `found=false` to `return false` and drop the flag.  No point in comparing the rest of the elements when you've already failed.  And the final `return false` should then be `return (listOfNumbers1.length!=0 || listOfNumbers2.length==0)`.

Comment: Correct, but I didn't want to confuse the OP who is still learning how to approach the question. Once s/he figures that out optimization is possible

Comment: Also, you can loop `i` up to the first length less the second length; a 5-character sequence won't be found if there's just 3 characters left. That gets rid of the internal length check each cycle.

Comment: @ose: That's not an "optimization"; it's avoiding a performance blunder.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of optimizations that can be done but they can make the code hard to understand without extensive comments... even then.

Comment: @ose: Once again, not it would not; the code would be clearer and perform better.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey this is a study example from a book, and the OP is learning step by step. You are of course correct and this is not disputed. All I am saying is that the OP is struggling to understand how to conceptualise this problem. The first step to this problem is understanding how to structure the look-ahead inner loop. Only once that is understood can you then go and apply the "improvements" you are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

```
class contains{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] list1 = {1,6,2,1,4,1,2,1,8};
        int[] list2 = {1,2,1};

        if(contains(list1, list2)){
            System.out.println("list2 found in list1");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("list2 not found in list1");
        }
    }

    public static boolean contains(int[] listOfNumbers1, int[] listOfNumbers2){
        if(listOfNumbers2.length > listOfNumbers1.length){
            return false;
        }
        for(int j = 0 ; j < listOfNumbers1.length - listOfNumbers2.length + 1; j++){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < listOfNumbers2.length; i++){
                if(listOfNumbers1[j+i] != listOfNumbers2[i]){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    if(i == listOfNumbers2.length-1){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. If you hardcode size of second array, why not go one step more nad hardcode whole answer - `return true` is much shorter/safer veriosn of given constant input.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you're right - apparently I'm too tired to be answering questions. I fixed my answer to be variable length and I'm going to bed.